# callback invoked in class extension

Tags: php

I'm working my way through php callbacks. I think I've covered the basics, but when working within class extensions I'm still hitting a brick wall somewhere for some time now, therefore it is time for some stack overflow [rubber duck programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)...!

Calling a callback from a class extension:

```
class myClass {
    function cb_check($function) {
        call_user_func($this->$function);
    }

    static function myFunction() {
        var_dump("Hello World");
    }   
}

class myExtClass extends myClass {
    function cb_invoke() {
        $this->cb_check('myFunction');
    }
}

$x = new myExtClass;
$x->cb_invoke();
```

Error message (or, notice and warning):

> Notice: Undefined property: myExtClass::$myFunction in F:\test.php on
>   line 5
>
> Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback,
>   no array or string given in F:\test.php on line 5

Line 5 is the [`call_user_func()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) above.

Does anybody have an idea what I am missing here?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `call_user_func(array($this, $function));` or `call_user_func('self::' . $function);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mark pointed out,

```
call_user_func($this->$function);
```

should be replaced by either

```
call_user_func(array($this, $function));
```

or

```
call_user_func('self::' . $function);
```

Thanks, Mark!

Answer (score 1):

While working with static classes you should have to use scope resolution operator :: you can not create the instance directly .

```
$x::myExtClass;
```

Try it.

Comment: Sorry, this won't work. More likely it'll lead to another error like _undefined class constant myExtClass_ or something like it.

Answer (score 1):

Your error arises because you've declared `myFunction()` to be `static`. Static methods don't belong to any specific instance of a class and therefore can't be accessed through the `$this` variable. Instead you use `self::myFunction()` to call the static method. The easiest way to make this happen is to build the string of the static method call and pass the string as the parameter to `call_user_func()`. Your code would work as-written if `myFunction()` were not static.

```php
class myClass {
    function cb_check($function) {
        // Build a static-method-style string
        call_user_func('self::' . $function);
    }

    static function myFunction() {
        var_dump("Hello World");
    }   
}

class myExtClass extends myClass {
    function cb_invoke() {
        $this->cb_check('myFunction');
    }
}

$x = new myExtClass;
$x->cb_invoke();
```

Comment: As-written doesn't work with or without the static function. I've tried both ways, and both result in the errors mentioned in my question. However, chaining the function with `self::` as a string works with and without static declaration.